# why is SVM cost function the norm of the hyperplane parameters, and not the mean square error?

Tags: svm

working through Dr. Ng's coursera course

[cost function intro](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/supplement/nhzyF/cost-function):

basically, you want to minimize the difference squared between your guess and the actual value

cost function for SVM: [this](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/supplement/pSe2X/lecture-slides) or [this](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/3eNnh/mathematics-behind-large-margin-classification)

he says the cost function is now the norm of the vector representing the hyperparameters: sqrt(theta_1^2 + theta_2^2... )

Why is that the case?

Comment: The [MSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) is not the only [loss function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function). If you look at [the illustration on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#/media/File:Svm_max_sep_hyperplane_with_margin.png), you will see that the minimizing the norm of the [normal vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) of the separating hyperplane _maximizes_ the separation, which is a good thing.

Comment: In particular, you should think about [loss functions for classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_functions_for_classification).

Answer (score 6):

Given a linearly separable data set, the intuition behind the SVM-algorithm is to **find a hyperplane that seperates both classes and maximizes the margin** *(which is twice the distance of the hyperplane to the closest data point)*.

So from all hyperplanes that seperate both classes, we want to find the one with the biggest margin *(to achieve the best generalization)*.

Let's imagine we have two parallel seperating hyperplanes defined by the vector $\theta$ and with no data points in between, their distance is then given by: $$m= \frac{2}{\|\theta\|}$$
To maximize this distance, the two hyperplanes must pass through data points of the opposing classes. 
In this case we can define another hyperplane in the middle *(with same distance to both hyperplanes and the same vector $\theta$)* that now has the margin $m$.

As you can see from the formula: the smaller $\|\theta\|$ the greater the margin $m$.

So **maximizing the margin $m$ is equivalent to minimizing $\|\theta\|$**. Thus, a separating hyperplane is optimal if it minimizes $\|\theta\|$.

This is just the rough intuition - if you want to go deeper into the maths behind it, I could recommend: http://www.svm-tutorial.com/2015/06/svm-understanding-math-part-3/